# Judit Polgar Vs Nigel Short. YouTube video

Tags: famous-players, women

Where can I find the video with the [game Judit Polgar Vs Nigel](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1111214) Short that by the year 2011 could be found on youtube? I'm interested in the video of the match and not in the game itself. According this this page (http://www.chesscreator.com/judit-polgar-vs-nigel-short-what-a-turnaround-6)'' This epic battle took place in New York City, 1994, at the Intel World Speed ​​Chess Tournament''

Could someone help me?

Comment: +1. I hope some day we can collect all about famous player in one Q&A.

Comment: I recall watching this video in 2011, but I believe the video was taken down from Youtube. Unless someone downloaded the video, only the original uploader would have a copy now.

Comment: [Here](http://www.chesscreator.com/judit-polgar-vs-nigel-short-what-a-turnaround-6) is a site that still has the carcase of the video embedded...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably part of [this collection](http://www.onlinechesslessons.net/shop/intel-grand-prix-series-1994-1995/), which has the footage available from the 1994-1995 season.  It costs money though...